# Determine if updating Laravel version was successfull

Tags: laravel, composer-php

After updating Laravel from 5.1 to 5.2, using `composer update` command, files `composer.json` and `composer.lock` have correct versions (5.2) written under `laravel/framework`. But the problem is, once I run `php artisan --version` in CLI it outputs `Laravel Framework version 5.1.45 (LTS)` and that confuses me.

Is there a way to be sure which version is now installed and being used?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Nope, will try right now

Comment: @CaddyDZ Getting `There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.` error. Can you tell me exact command I should use to clear the cache?

Comment: Have you tried to clear configuration cache? `php artisan config:clear`